# python class inherit affects property?

Tags: python, inheritance, properties

I met a weird issue. please see the code I paste below.
in myclass I have a @property datef.
I can set get the property;
but when I make myclass inherit from mybase,
I cannot set the property any more. 
Why?

```
class mybase(object):
    pass

class myclass(mybase):
    @property     
    def dataf(self): return 1

var = myclass()
print var.dataf
var.dataf = 33
print var.__dict__
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You don't define a setter method for the property.

Comment: Isn't it because mybase inherits from `object`? This changes the way properties work.

Comment: Why are you trying to override the property's value? Doesn't this kinda defeat the point of a property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define property getter and setter:

```
class mybase(object):
    pass

class myclass(mybase):
    def dataf_get(self): return getattr(self, "_data_f", None)
    def dataf_set(self, value): self._data_f = value
    dataf = property(dataf_get, dataf_set)

var = myclass()
print var.dataf
>> None
var.dataf = 33
print var.dataf
>> 33
print var.__dict__
>> {'_data_f': 33}
```

Comment: Alternate syntax: decorator for setter is `@dataf.setter` (new in 2.6)

Answer (score 1):

The @property decorator [only works properly](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-new-style-class) with new-style classes.

If you tried

```
class myclass:
    @property     
    def dataf(self): return 1
```

then `myclass` is an old-style class, so don't expect @property to work properly.

When instead you make `myclass` a subclass of `mybase` which in turn inherits from `object`, you are making `myclass` a new-style class. Now @property works properly.

Now you need to define a setter if you wish to be able to set the property.

```
class mybase(object):
    pass

class myclass(mybase):
    @property     
    def dataf(self): return 1

    @dataf.setter
    def dataf(self, value):
        self._dataf = value

var = myclass()
print var.dataf
var.dataf = 33
print var.__dict__
```

yields

```
1
{'_dataf': 33}
```

Comment: @Marcin: No, I think this is correct. The only explanation for the OP being able to "set" the property without a setter is that the original class was old-style, i.e. the property decorator was ignored and the class attribute `dataf` was being reassigned to 33.

Comment: @Marcin: The OP states, "but when I make myclass inherent [sic] from mybase, I cannot set the property any more." This implies that he first tried making `myclass` NOT inherit from `mybase`. Since he was able to set the property, it must have been because `myclass` was no longer a new-style class.

Comment: @Marcin: I am new turn python from C#. the property doesn't make sense for me. for example you have a class - myclass has a public field - dataf, later on you want to change the dataf's logic, not just return the data, you want put some logic before return, so you need change dataf to function, but you don't want to change ever place where you are using the public field. but in python, after you set the field - dataf = 33, the get function won't be execute any more ( return 1 )

Comment: @alex: Actually, even after you set `var.dataf = 33`, the next time you access `var.dataf` the getter function will be called (and it will return 1). If this is not clear, post runnable code, with the output you are getting and the output you desire.

Comment: @unutbu it does not execute the getter function, if I don't inherit from object. it is confused, inherit or not inherit from a object, has hug difference. <pre><code> [code] `#class mybase(object): # pass class myclass(): \@property def dataf(self): return 1 \@dataf.setter def dataf(self, value): self._dataf = value var = myclass() print var.dataf var.dataf = 33 print var.dataf print var.__dict__ `[code]</pre></code>

Comment: @alex: The @property decorator only works with new-style classes. Don't use it if the class does not inherit from `object`. Nowadays, all classes you define should be new-style classes. Looking forward, in Python3, all classes will by default be new-style (even without explicitly including `object` in the bases).

Comment: @Lenna Perhaps OP's code is not representative of their problem, but the code shown shows new-style classes.